# In docker, why does mounting a data volume container to a container makes it stop working?

Tags: docker

I am using [this docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/jerob/docker-ispconfig/) and was able to successfully run it as a container(using the docker run command present in dockerhub). But I wanted to make the /var/www/ folder of the said container to be persistent.

So, I tried this command to run the container with a volume mapped to it.

```
docker run -v /home/ejandra/ispconfig:/var/www --name ispconfig -e MAILMAN_EMAIL_HOST=test.com -e MAILMAN_EMAIL=test@test.com -e MAILMAN_PASS=pass -d -p 20:20 -p 21:21 -p 30000:30000 -p 30001:30001 -p 30002:30002 -p 30003:30003
-p 30004:30004 -p 30005:30005 -p 30006:30006 -p 30007:30007 -p 30008:30008 -p 30009:30009 -p 80:80 -p 443:443 -p 8080:8080 -p 53:53 -p 2222:22 jerob/docker-ispconfig /start.sh
```

This is to map to a data volume whichever the contents of `/var/www` are. The volume mapping works because whenever I try to add a new text file to `/var/www` via shell access, i see the file in `/home/ejandra/ispconfig`. However, when I go to https://my-ip:8080 , my browser says, "the site can't be reached". What could be the reason that my container suddenly stopped working after adding a data volume?

Comment: I tried your docker container, it throws an error `Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:53: bind: address already in use.` then the container stops. If that's the case, you cannot access https://localhost:8080 because the container is not working.

Comment: Hello, I think that just means that your 0.0.0.0:53 is in use. You have to change the ports or stop the process running at 0.0.0.0:53.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to achieve what you wanted by first copying all the stuff to the folder on the host machine and then running the container. So, this is what I did:

First, run the container as you normally do:

```
sudo docker run -name ispconfig -e MAILMAN_EMAIL_HOST=test.com \
     -e MAILMAN_EMAIL=test@test.com -e MAILMAN_PASS=pass -d \
     -p 20:20 -p 21:21 -p 30000:30000 -p 30001:30001 -p 30002:30002 \
     -p 30003:30003 -p 30004:30004 -p 30005:30005 -p 30006:30006 \
     -p 30007:30007 -p 30008:30008 -p 30009:30009 -p 80:80 -p 443:443 \
     -p 8080:8080 -p 53:53 -p 2222:22 jerob/docker-ispconfig /start.sh
```

Then go inside the container and tar and copy the existing folders to the host machine:

```
$ sudo docker exec -ti ispconfig bash
root@398592d4afe9:/# DEFAULT_ROUTE=$(ip route show default \
                    | awk '/default/ {print $3}')
root@398592d4afe9:/var/www# tar -cvzf /tmp/www.tar.gz /var/www/
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
/var/www/
/var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/
/var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/ispconfig/
/var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/ispconfig/.php-fcgi-starter
/var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/apps/
/var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/apps/.php-fcgi-starter
/var/www/ispconfig
/var/www/html/
/var/www/html/index.html
/var/www/apps/
/var/www/webalizer/
root@398592d4afe9:/# scp -rv /tmp/www.tar.gz nwani@${DEFAULT_ROUTE}:
The authenticity of host '172.17.42.1 (172.17.42.1)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is 7d:77:b7:54:3a:a5:00:37:94:55:4b:68:8d:2c:89:26.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
nwani@172.17.42.1's password:
```

Then exit out of the container and delete it.

```
root@398592d4afe9:/# exit
$ sudo docker rm -f ispconfig
```

Then extract the copied tar ball:

```
$ sudo tar -xf /tmp/www.tar.gz -C /home/nwani/
$ sudo ls /home/nwani/var/www/ -l
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 2 5002 5003 4096 Sep  3  2015 apps
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Sep  3  2015 html
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   34 Sep  3  2015 ispconfig -> /usr/local/ispconfig/interface/web
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Sep  3  2015 php-fcgi-scripts
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Sep  3  2015 webalizer
```

Now, run the container again, but this time, mount the data directory:

```
sudo docker run -name ispconfig -v /home/nwani/var/www/:/var/www \
     -e MAILMAN_EMAIL_HOST=test.com -e MAILMAN_EMAIL=test@test.com \
     -e MAILMAN_PASS=pass -d -p 20:20 -p 21:21 -p 30000:30000 \
     -p 30001:30001 -p 30002:30002 -p 30003:30003 -p 30004:30004 \
     -p 30005:30005 -p 30006:30006 -p 30007:30007 -p 30008:30008 \
     -p 30009:30009 -p 80:80 -p 443:443 -p 8080:8080 -p 53:53 \
     -p 2222:22 jerob/docker-ispconfig /start.sh
```

Comment: This worked for me without any hassles Sir! Thanks! I have a question, why is it needed to copy the folder that I want to persist first? The docker documentation which I followed (https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/) did not explain anything about this or did I miss it?

Comment: @nowrn29 Because the docker image which you are using, assumes that certain directories, with certain symlinks, with certain content, with certain permissions will already be present at the location `/var/www` :)